# Difference in behavior when using "yield from" with an Iterator or a Generator

Tags: php, iterator, generator

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) it if possible to delegate generation from any Traversable object. However I see the difference between `yield from {a Generator instance}` and `yield from {an Iterator instance}`.

## An example.

This piece of code has an `Iterator` and a `Generator` that are doing the same: they provide the "1, 2, 3" sequence:

```
$iterator = new class implements \Iterator {

    private $values = [1, 2, 3];

    public function current()
    {
        return current($this->values);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        next($this->values);
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key(this->values);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return current($this->values) !== false;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        reset($this->values);
    }
};

$generator = (function ()
{
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
})();
```

But when I try to `yield from` them, I've got different results. Let's play with this function:

```
function skipOne(\Iterator $iterator)
{
    $iterator->next();
    yield from $iterator;
}
```

With a generator everything works as expected:

```
foreach (skipOne($generator) as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}

Output:
int(2)
int(3)
```

But with an Iterator it doesn't skip the first number:

```
foreach (skipOne($iterator) as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}

Output:
int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
```

I've found that `yield from` operator cause `$iterator->rewind()` invocation by some reason. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything *wrong*.

`yield from` will attempt to `rewind` something that's capable of being rewound, but generators are not, they only go forward.

That`s the reason your code works as you expect in the first example, and not in the second.

You could wrap your `$iterator` in a generator, and you'd get the same result.

```
$wrappedIterator = (function($iterator) {
    foreach ($iterator as $value) {
        yield $value;
    }
})($iterator);
```

You are simply takind "advantage" of the one-use nature of the generators, since they can only go forward and never be rewound.

They same would happen with `foreach`, for example, since it also attempts to rewind whatever is looping about.

If you simply did

```
$iterator->next();
foreach ($iterator as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

you would also get:

> int(1)
>
> int(2)
>
> int(3)

In both cases (`yield from` and `foreach`) the iterator will be rewound.

Although if you tried

```
$generator->next();
foreach ($generator as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

you would get a fatal error.

In your case, since when `yield from` is not capable of rewinding the object of its affections it doesn't complain and proceeds as if nothing happened, it can be confusing.

You can easily verify the behavior by checking [this](https://3v4l.org/c2ode).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is really confusing, when my function `skipOne` that is a generator, gives different results without a reason. Could you please point me out where is specified that `yield from` attempts to rewind?

Comment: I have not found the specification anywhere, to be honest. Looked hard first time I encountered this, but there is none I could find (as opposed to `foreach` behavior, that's properly documented). But empirical testing will confirm it.

Comment: thanks for the workaround you've provided. I solved the issue in exactly this way: by conversion Iterator -> Generator. But the question remains. I want to realize whether it is a PHP bug or my misunderstanding of the documentation.

Comment: @Magomogo Likely neither. It's just a documentation ommission. The behaviour is not buggy, is simply not documented.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `yield from` will call `$iterator->rewind()`.

Generators cannot be rewound, because their `rewind()` is implemented to do nothing.

[From the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.comparison.php):

> Generators are forward-only iterators, and cannot be rewound once iteration has started. This also means that the same generator can't be iterated over multiple times: the generator will need to be rebuilt by calling the generator function again.

So if you wish to have the same behavior as Generators, you have two options.

### Option 1: No-op Rewind

Simply leave the `rewind()` method of your `Iterator` empty, and move any rewind code to the constructor of the iterator.

```php
class MyIterator implements \Iterator
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // put rewind code here
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

This will make your iterators less reusable, while also making it unclear from outside code why the iterator is not behaving like a regular iterator. So use this option with caution.

### Options 2: Use `NoRewindIterator`

[`NoRewindIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.norewinditerator.php) is an [SPL iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) class that [decorates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) another iterator.

```php
$noRewindIterator = new \NoRewindIterator($iterator);
```

It will behave identically to the `$iterator` it is given, with the exception of the `rewind()` method. When `$noRewindIterator->rewind()` is called, nothing will happen.

This has the advantage of allowing you to write normal rewind-able iterators, while also being able to do partial iteration.

Here's how your `skipOne()` function can use `NoRewindIterator`:

```php
function skipOne(\Iterator $iterator)
{
    $iterator->next();
    yield from new \NoRewindIterator($iterator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield.from) said `The outer generator will then yield all values from the inner generator, object, or array until that is no longer valid, after which execution will continue in the outer generator.`

`All` is one from keywords here. PHP [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.3.1/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L7347) is proof that too.